# Angular search in a table

Tags: html, angularjs, search, angularjs-scope

I want to make a search on the column SN in a table.

there many information in my table, I want to be able to search based on `SN` but when I add the `filter` it does not even load my table

This is what I did:
in My controler my List is filled :

```
 $scope.List = {};


 MyServices.getList()
.success(function (data) {
    angular.forEach(data, function (value, index) {
            $scope.List[value.SN] = {
                Description: value.Description,
                SN: value.SN
            }
    });
})
.error(function (error) {
    $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
});
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<label>Search: <input ng-model="search.SN"></label>
<tr ng-repeat="V in List| filter:search">
    <td>{{V.SN}}</td>
    <td>{{V.Description}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your ngModel is `search.SN`, so your filter also should be `search.SN`.

Comment: I did what you suggested but still the same problem. I have read this link and it seems like what I did should work, I don't know what is the problem.
https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must write as follow:

```
   <label>Search: <input ng-model="search.SN"></label>
    <tr ng-repeat="V in List| filter: {SN: search.SN}">
    <td>{{V.SN}}</td>
    <td>{{V.Description}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: it's not working. my List is $scope.List = {}; how can I solve it?

Comment: I don't understand what is problem, can you show `$scope.List` elements?

Comment: I Updated the question, would you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the object declaration on the input field. It will match the whole object for your specified value on the input field:

```
<label>Search: <input ng-model="search"></label>
<tr ng-repeat="V in List| filter: search">
  <td>{{V.SN}}</td>
  <td>{{V.Description}}</td>
</tr>
```